# Do the intersection of three longest cycles implies the intersection of three longest paths?

Tags: graph-theory

The following is an annoying open problem in graph theory:

> Do any three longest paths in a connected finite graph have a vertex in common?

Thinking about it a bit I came to the conclusion that the following must be an equally interesting problem:

> Do any three longest cycles in a $2-$connected finite graph have a vertex in common?

I would like to know if this problem has already been proposed and studied.

More importantly, I want to know one of the two implies the other, so that is my question.

First I thought that the cycle-version would imply the path-version since you can convert the longest paths into cycles by adding an edge between its ends. However, this might not yield a longest cycle. In the image, the red and blue paths are longest paths, but the red and blue cycles are not longest cycles.

[image]

The same image justifies that removing an edge from a longest cycle might not yield a longest path, but I guess this was expected.

Comment: Yes, the problem about longest cycles has already been posed and studied. See page 72 of a survey by Shabbir et al. Intersecting longest paths and longest cycles

Comment: Well worth adding, a short paper by Nirankush Sarkar "Any three longest paths in a connected graph has a common vertex" appeared in [arXiv](https://arxiv.org/abs/2006.16245) in 2020. However, it is not clear to me yet whether the proof given in this article is correct.